# Export Apple Mail Database for import into Outlook 2016 for Windows

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, ms-office

I have to migrate to Windows PC for the first time. All my work is email oriented and I have tons of emails on my Apple Mail email client and also I have saved a lot of them on my hard drive as .mbox files after exporting them from Apple mail.

So how can I export all these files from Apple Mail and import into  Outlook 2016 for Windows?

Comment: You are aware you have simply swapped one set of limitations for another...?

Comment: Close Voters:  This is an **on topic** question about exporting data from an Apple Application to a Windows application; it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already exported your apple mail database as .mbox files then there is no other way but to use an email conversion tool that will convert the .mbox files into .pst files in order to import them into outlook 2016 for windows. One application that I am aware of is apple mail to pst converter: http://applemailtopst.com/buy-apple-mail-to-pst-converter/, that has the capability to convert the apple mail files directly from apple mail and that too on mac.

I got this information from their website and in order to confirm its proper functioning, you can download its trial version which is free of cost.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to get Apple MBOX files to Outlook on Windows was to use a conversion tool.

[Stellar Phoenix makes a MBOX to PST conversion  tool](https://www.stellarinfo.com/email-tools/mbox-to-pst-converter.php) that I have used previously and it worked perfectly.   The price is quite reasonable at $39 and they offer you the ability to preview the conversion to ensure it will work for free.

However, please note that the last time I used this was for a 2013 conversion.  Since then I personally, and advise my clients, friends, and family to use a cloud based email solution (like O365 with hosted Exchange) so you avoid this problem in the future.